# Effective gesture rendering in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm newbie to Flutter (but had an experience writing Android applications) and want to implement a simple paint app, where your gestures are rendering on empty canvas. The most straightforward approach is  to save gesture points and then render them one by one on every `CustomPainter` `build()` call, but it's too ineffective. Supposing that screen is being "cleared" before rendering new frame (I don't know if it's case for Flutter), I want something like this:

> 1) Draw gesture to some "canvas" object, extract the pixels data or
>   whatever to save what have just been drawn.
>
> 2) On next gesture event, restore preserved pixels data to
>   "canvas" and append new gesture to this canvas.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zu-do2luSAo) actually did an entire tutorial on exactly that with his source code [here](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?v=zu-do2luSAo&event=video_description&q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fiampawan%2Ffluttersignatureview&redir_token=ynV6U7KzfLv_JiSirBRtgoG4rp58MTU0MzYyMTE5MEAxNTQzNTM0Nzkw)

Comment: Wow, nice find, will take a closer look

Comment: Well, in the end of the day he's just rebuilding all lines on every `paint` call. But he uses good old Canvas from Android SDK, so I can take it from here. Thanks!

Comment: However the guy did it is probably the better way, he did after all appear on Google's official channel